# Highcharts Scatter plot - Add series from database as a different color

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to build a highcharts scatter chart from a dataset with two series. The first is called 'inperson' and should be plotted in blue, the second series is called 'other' and needs to be plotted in red. I can't seem to get the second series to show up on my chart.

Here's my code:

```
var options = {
  chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    type: 'scatter',
    plotBorderWidth: 1,
    zoomType: 'xy'
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },

    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return  "<br/><br/> "  + "Date: " + this.x +   "<br/><br/> " + "Yr: "+ this.y + "<br/><br/>" + contact_notes[this.point.index];
  }},


  xAxis: {
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
           day: '%m/%d'    //ex- 01 Jan 2016
        }
    },
yAxis: {
        gridLineWidth: 0,
    },


  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{}],
};



  vardata={
  "chart_data": {
    "contact_date": [
      "01/01",
      "02/06",
      "04/03",
      "08/09",
      "10/11",
      "12/27"
    ],
    "other": [
      2019.0,
      2017.0,
      2018.0,
      2017.0,
      2018.0,
      2017.0
    ],
    "inperson": [
      2019.0,
      2018.0,
      2017.0,
      NaN,
      2019.0,
      2017.0,
    ],
    "contact_notes": [
      "AA",
      "BB",
      "CC",
      "DD",
      "EE",
      "FF",
    ]
  }
};


options.xAxis.categories = data['chart_data']['contact_date'];
options.series[0].data = data['chart_data']['in-person'];
options.series[0].name = 'in-person'
options.series[0].color = '#3232ff';

var contact_notes = data['chart_data']['contact_notes'];

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

chart.addSeries({name:'other', color:'#b20000', data: data['chart_data']['other']}, false);
chart.redraw();


Highcharts.chart('container', options);
```

The last few lines (addSeries and redraw) don't seem to be working. Any suggestions on how I can fix?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last line of your code (`Highcharts.chart` constructor method) - resets the chart to the state without added series.

Here's working [JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0uLajhcn/1/) without that call to constructor.

P.S. BTW, you have two typos in your code: `vardata` and `options.series[0].data = data['chart_data']['in-person'];` which should access `['inperson']`